# Multiple RDS vs DNS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-route53

have a problem I was hoping someone could help me with. We have two RDS read slaves that we have our app servers round-robin to for data reads (DNS in Route53).

Well, yesterday those RDSes got restarted by AWS and changed IPs and it all stopped working. We have a CNAME to the master that the app uses for writes, which is more resilient, but you can't round-robin CNAMEs. You also can't elastic-IP a RDS. What is a good solution to using multiple read slaves from an arbitrary app (not changing the app to make it call the API to figure it out) that's resilient to restarts/IP changes?

Comment: If you don't want to change the original app to utilize AWS as designed, you could write another app to call the rds/route53 api's and monitor for changes and update?  Or a cloudwatch alarm that just notifies you on rds reboots.  The good news is that rds reboots don't happen often depending on your maintenance settings.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered doing weighted round robin?  You can configure them with Route 53 and use CNAMEs.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-weighted